# jquery.validate: multiple fields add up to value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, validation

I'm working on a form where the user enters a total, then enters more values into other fields that represent a dividing up of that total.  For example:

```
<input type="text" name="total" />
<input type="text" name="portion[1]" />
<input type="text" name="portion[2]" />
<!-- and so on -->
<input type="text" name="portion[n]" />
```

If the user enters 123.45 into total, then they need to fill out the portions 1 - n such that their values add up to 123.45.  Each portion field is required to be a positive number or 0 but those are the only other restrictions on them.

The jquery.validate plugin has an equalTo validation method, but this can only seem to cope with a single field, rather than a set.

Is there a way to

1. Define a validation rule that will validate the total of the group of fields against the total field
2. Get a single message to display for the group of fields if they don't add up

Comment: I am also looking for the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714366/jquery-validate-how-do-i-add-validation-which-checks-the-sum-of-multiple-fields) looks like it has some answers that could be useful in solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function with a jquery event

```
  function Mvalidate()
    {
    var total=$('[name=total]').val();

    var n=10; // no of portions 
    var partialsum=0;
    for(var i=0;i<n; i++)
    {
    var t=$("[name=portion["+i+"]]").val();
    partialsum+=parseFloat(t);

    }

    if(partialsum<total)
    alert("Portions add up not complete!");

    }

$("#checkbutton").click(function()
  {
  Mvalidate();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

@Krishnan:

according [Jquery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) the

> $('.total').

is a class selector, isn't it? If you want to look for an element with a name attribute, you have to write it as follow:

```
$("[name='total']").val();
$("[name='portion["+i+"]']").val();
```

If you know there is only an input field with that name, you can use

```
$("input[name='total']").val();
```

Comment: I've got classes and IDs set up for grabbing the fields as needed, but don't forget val() only grabs the value of the first matching form control.  To get them all you'd need to do $('selector').each () with some kind of callback that keeps a running total of all the vals